# Identify short signal peaks with rolling time frame in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify all peaks from my sensor readings data. The smallest peak can be lesser than 10 amplitude and largest can be more than 400 amplitude. The rolling time window is not fixed as one peak can arrive in 6 hours vs second one in another 3 hours. I tried wavelet transform and python peak identification but that is only working for higher peaks. How do I resolve this? [Here is signal image link, all peaks in Grey color I am identifying and in blue is my algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnfXF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
It is hard to provide you with a detailed answer without knowing your data's **sampling rate** and the **duration** of the peaks. From what I see in your example image they seem all over the place!

I don't think that wavelets will be of any use for your problem.

A recipe that I like to use to despike data is:

1. Smooth your input `data` using a median filter (a 11 points median filter generally does the trick for me): `smoothed=scipy.signal.medfilt(data, window_len=11)`
2. Compute a `noise` array by subtracting `smoothed` from `data`: `noise=data-smoothed`
3. Create a `despiked_data` array from `data`:

   `despiked_data=np.zeros_like(data)`

   `np.copyto(despiked_data, data)`
4. Then every time the noise exceeds a user defined threshold (`mythreshold`), replace the corresponding value in `despiked_data` with nan values: `despiked_data[np.abs(noise)>mythreshold]=np.nan`

You may later interpolate the output `despiked_data` array but if your intent is simply to identify the spikes, you don't even need to run this extra step.